# Pyspark grouping , joining and covert to json

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I Have two spark Df.

1. User Df

   - userId
   - UserName
   - Address
2. Order Df

   - UserId
   - ProductName
   - ProductDesc
   - CategoryName
   - CategoryId
   - CategoryDesc
   - Price

Sample data:
User Df

```
+------+----+--------+
|userId|name|Addreshh|
+------+----+--------+
|     1|Sufi|   Reons|
|     2|Ragu|  Random|
+------+----+--------+
```

Order df

```
+------+-----------+-----------+------------+----------+------------+-----+
|userId|ProductName|ProductDesc|CategoryName|CategoryId|CategoryDesc|Price|
+------+-----------+-----------+------------+----------+------------+-----+
|     1|         A1|      A1Dec|           A|         1|        Adec|    5|
|     1|         A2|      A2Dec|           A|         1|        Adec|   10|
|     1|         B1|      A1Dec|           B|         2|        Bdec|   11|
|     2|         B4|      A4Dec|           B|         2|        Bdec|   15|
+------+-----------+-----------+------------+----------+------------+-----+
```

**I need to group and aggregate(create nested schema) order df and join with user df. Then create a json file for each record**

eg:-
Json 1

```
{
      "userId": 1,
      "neme": "sufi",
      "address": "Reons",
      "order": [
        {
          "name": "A1",
          "price": 5,
          "category": {
            "Id": 1,
            "name": "A",
            "desc": "ADesc"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "A2",
          "price": 10,
          "category": {
            "Id": 1,
            "name": "A",
            "desc": "ADesc"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "B1",
          "price": 11,
          "category": {
            "Id": 2,
            "name": "B",
            "desc": "BDesc"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Orderdf = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("1", "A1", "A1Dec","A","1","Adec",5),
    ("1", "A2", "A2Dec","A","1","Adec",10),
    ("1", "B1", "A1Dec","B","2","Bdec",11),
    ("2", "B4", "A4Dec","B","2","Bdec",15)
], ["userId", "ProductName", "ProductDesc","CategoryName","CategoryId","CategoryDesc","Price"])

Comment: userdf = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("1", "Sufi", "Reons"),
    ("2", "Ragu", "Random"),
], ["userId", "name", "Address"])

Comment: the desc column does not match any columns in orderdf

Comment: @mck The desc is inside category object. That is Categorydesc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the two dataframes and use `collect_list` to collect the orders for each user. Write json files as output and partition it using userId. There will be two folders created for each userId, and each folder will contain one json file. Spark can't rename the files or move them, so you'll probably need some `os` operations to rename/move them as you wish.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

orderdf2 = orderdf.select('userId',
    F.struct(
        F.col('ProductName').alias('name'),
        F.col('Price').alias('price'),
        F.struct(
            F.col('CategoryId').alias('Id'),
            F.col('CategoryName').alias('name'),
            F.col('CategoryDesc').alias('desc')
        ).alias('category')
    ).alias('order')
).groupBy('userId').agg(
    F.collect_list('order').alias('order')
)

userdf.join(
    orderdf2, 'userId'
).groupBy(
    'userId','name','address'
).agg(
    F.collect_list('order').alias('order')
).write.partitionBy('userId').json('result')
```

```
==> userId=1/part-00144-845806db-0700-4585-bb45-01648432abc1.c000.json <==
{"name":"Sufi","address":"Reons","order":[{"name":"A1","price":5,"category":{"Id":"1","name":"A","desc":"Adec"}},{"name":"A2","price":10,"category":{"Id":"1","name":"A","desc":"Adec"}},{"name":"B1","price":11,"category":{"Id":"2","name":"B","desc":"Bdec"}}]}

==> userId=2/part-00189-845806db-0700-4585-bb45-01648432abc1.c000.json <==
{"name":"Ragu","address":"Random","order":[{"name":"B4","price":15,"category":{"Id":"2","name":"B","desc":"Bdec"}}]}
```

Comment: How can i perform left join?

Comment: userdf.join(orderdf, 'userId', 'left')

Comment: what about group order df before joining. I think that will give better performance.

Comment: doesn't matter if you group the `orderdf` first and then join, or join then group by. I'm doing the latter. performance difference shouldn't be obvious

Comment: What I added is just sample df. like that I have 30 df, and I need to group each df and join with other. finally i need to create Sigle json file(each df has millions of records).
What will be the best approach.

Comment: @SuFi I have edited my answer to do the group by first, and then join, which could be slightly faster. I don't understand the structures of your 30 dataframes and how the grouping/joining operations look like, so sorry that I can't answer this question confidently. Feel free to open another question and provide sufficient details for others to help you.

Comment: How can i add default value if column not e
f.col('CategoryName').alias('name') i need to add default value is column not exist.
@mck

Comment: @SuFi please open another question. Comments are not intended for extended discussion, and it's unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Spark-sql solution:

```
 val df = spark.sql(""" with t1 (
 select  1 c1,   'Sufi' c2, 'Reons' c3  union all
 select  2 c1,   'Ragu' c2, 'Random' c3
  )  select   c1  userId,   c2  name,   c3 Addreshh    from t1
""")

 val order_df = spark.sql(""" with t1 (
 select  1 c1,   'A1' c2, 'A1Dec' c3, 'A' c4, 1 c5,   'Adec' c6, 5 c7    union all
 select  1 c1,   'A2' c2, 'A2Dec' c3, 'A' c4, 1 c5,   'Adec' c6, 10 c7    union all
 select  1 c1,   'B1' c2, 'A1Dec' c3, 'B' c4, 2 c5,   'Bdec' c6, 11 c7    union all
 select  2 c1,   'B4' c2, 'A4Dec' c3, 'B' c4, 2 c5,   'Bdec' c6, 15 c7
  )  select   c1  userId,   c2  ProductName,   c3  ProductDesc,   c4  CategoryName,   c5  CategoryId,   c6  CategoryDesc,   c7 Price    from t1
""")

df.createOrReplaceTempView("cust")
order_df.createOrReplaceTempView("order")

val dj_src1 = spark.sql(""" select userId, collect_list(named_struct('name',ProductName,'price',Price,'category',category )) order from 
( select userId, ProductName, Price, named_struct('id', CategoryId,'name',CategoryName,'desc', CategoryDesc ) category from order ) temp
group by 1  
""")

dj_src1.createOrReplaceTempView("src1")

val dj2 = spark.sql(""" select a.userId, a.name, a.Addreshh, b.order 
from cust a join 
src1 b on
a.userId=b.userid
""")

dj2.toJSON.show(false)

+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"userId":1,"name":"Sufi","Addreshh":"Reons","order":[{"name":"A1","price":5,"category":{"id":1,"name":"A","desc":"Adec"}},{"name":"A2","price":10,"category":{"id":1,"name":"A","desc":"Adec"}},{"name":"B1","price":11,"category":{"id":2,"name":"B","desc":"Bdec"}}]}|
|{"userId":2,"name":"Ragu","Addreshh":"Random","order":[{"name":"B4","price":15,"category":{"id":2,"name":"B","desc":"Bdec"}}]}                                                                                                                                          |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```